# Deletion of words between 2 matching words in a string in python

Tags: python, string

Suppose there is a string

```
x="India is the country of festivals. India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock"
```

and suppose
`n="India`"

then I want result as

```
x="India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock"
```

So what I mean is from a string I want to delete all sentences between\till a particular word which is repeated 2nd time. Hope, my question is clear. I couldn't explain it in a better way

Comment: And what if there's another repetition in the sentence? (like what if `India` occurs 4 times?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **re**

```
import re
x="India is the country of festivals. India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock"
n = 'India'
lst = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(n, x)]

x[:lst[0]] + x[lst[1]:]

# 'India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock'
```

Comment: This works for the given example. It would be more robust if you check the word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, use built-in `str.count()` and `str.split()`.

```py
x = 'India is the country of festivals. India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock'
n = 'India'
if x.split().count(n) >= 2: # be sure to count at **word** level
    pre, mid, post = x.split(n, 2)
    print(pre + n + post)
else:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this using `x.find` and a starting point

```
x = "India is the country of festivals. India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock"
n = "India"
first = x.find(n, 0)
second = x.find(n, first+1)
print(x[0:first] + x[second:len(x)])  # 'India is known for its rich culture. National bird of India is peacock'
```